# spring-data-couchbase : Update query is not woring while spring boot migration

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

We are trying to migrate to spring boot 3.0,
Spring data couchbase has version : 5.1.4
We had previous update query which used work. now after migrating to springboot 3 we are getting below error for our update query :

we have added @DefaultScope in Repository.
priceDetails is bucket name

[2023-10-16T11:10:34.030Z] {"mdc":{"traceId":"f140f7a2d182b6facf2a0b993c7a7fc3","spanId":"ad88feae139c7536"},"timestamp":"2023-10-16 11:10:58.589","level":"ERROR","logger":"com.amdocs.catalog.common.event.ReleaseEventCoordinator"s","message":"Publish failed","exception":"\ncom.couchbase.client.core.error.IndexFailureException: The server reported an issue with the underlying index {"completed":true,"coreId":"0x5c5970900000001","errors":[{"code":12003,"message":"Keyspace not found in CB datastore: default:priceDetails.priceDetails.priceDetails","retry":false}],"httpStatus":500,"idempotent":false,"lastDispatchedFrom":"10.254.30.111:51098","lastDispatchedTo":"ilvpbg2647.corp.amdocs.com:49873","requestId":115,"requestType":"QueryRequest","retried":0,"service":{"bucket":"priceDetails","operationId":"null","scope":"priceDetails","statement":"UPDATE `priceDetails` SET updatedByCatalogChangeId = $catalogChangeId, exposureTimePeriod.previousEndDateTime = exposureTimePeriod.endDateTime ,exposureTimePeriod.endDateTime = $effectiveDate WHERE id IN $ids  AND exposureTimePeriod.startDateTime <= $effectiveDate AND $effectiveDate < exposureTimePeriod.endDateTime AND `_class` = \"com.amdocs.catalog.domain.ProductOfferingPriceDAO\"","type":"query"},"timeoutMs":5000,"timings":{"dispatchMicros":3786,"totalDispatchMicros":3786,"totalMicros":32478}}\n\tat com.couchbase.client.core.io.netty.query.QueryChunkResponseParser.errorsToThrowable(QueryChunkResponseParser.java:176)\n\tat com.couchbase.client.core.io.netty.query.QueryChunkResponseParser.lambda$error$10(QueryChunkResponseParser.java:128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)\n\tat com.couchbase.client.core.io.netty.query.QueryChunkResponseParser.error(QueryChunkResponseParser.java:128)\n\tat

tried removing @DefaultScope nbut it didn't help.
Looks like bucket name is not getting calculated correctly

Comment: If you were not using scopes and collections before, there is no need to introduce scopes and collections when migrating.  If you wish to introduce scopes and collections, the documentation is here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.collections

Comment: Keyspace not found in CB datastore: default:priceDetails.priceDetails.priceDetails" .. {"bucket":"priceDetails","operationId":"null","scope":"priceDetails","statement":"UPDATE priceDetails 

keyspace names are formed with default:bucketName.scopeName.collectionName and in your case the configured bucketName is priceDetails, the scopeName (either in the configuration, annotation or in the code) is priceDetails and the collectionName (specified in the @Query) is also priceDetails.